# How to make spark streaming process multiple batches?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Spark uses parallelism, however while testing my application and looking at the sparkUI, under the streaming tab I often notice under "active batches" that the status of one is "processing" and the rest are "queued".  Is there a parameter I can configure to make Spark process multiple batches simultaneously?

Note:  I am using `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` greater than 1, but that doesn't seem to apply to batch processing (?)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using Yarn to launch your spark stream.

Yarn queue your batches because he don't have enough resources to launch simultaneously your stream/spark batch.

you can try limit ressource use by yarn with :

```
-driver-memory -> memory for the driver
--executor-memory -> memory for worker
-num-executors -> number of distinct yarn containers
--executor-cores -> number of threads you get inside each executor
```

for exemple :

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 800m \
--executor-memory 800m \
--num-executors 4 \
--class my.class \
myjar
```

Comment: You're correct I am using YARN.  The environment I'm running on has plenty of resources, I did however try to lower the memory usage for the executors, but that had no impact.  I still get an ever increasing list of "queued" batch processes.

Comment: try increasing `--executor-memory` to 5GB and include `--executor-cores` 4 or any number to increase parallelism within an executer. Don't forget to give `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`.